# How to make event on textbox.text_changed (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i have no idea with creating event textchanged or somethink as this for textBox.
It will be doing some form of find when text changed.

[Image with code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QW1OB.jpg)

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    <br />
    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <p>
        <p>
            @Html.TextBox("searchString")
        <input type="submit" value="Find" />
    </p>
    </p>
    }
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

I want it call this (This is written right):

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString))
        {
            return View(db.Regions.ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            List<Regions> collectionOfRegions = db.Regions.ToList();
            return View(collectionOfRegions.Where(x => x.MatchBetweenAllFields(searchString)));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Replace TextBox**

```
@Html.TextBox("YourTextBox", new { onchange="yourForm.submit();"})
```

**And add JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#YourTextBox').change(function () {
              //Content to send 
              var yourText = $(this).val();

              //Post the content of your Textbox to your "YourAction" action in "YourController"
              $.post('@Url.Action("YourAction","YourController")', { "YourText" : yourText }, function(data){
                  //Do something with the results here
                  alert(data);
              });
            });
        });
</script>
```

**Also edit controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public void YourAction(string yourText)
{
      if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(yourText))
    {
        return View(db.Regions.ToList());
    }
    else
    {
        List<Regions> collectionOfRegions = db.Regions.ToList();
        return View(collectionOfRegions.Where(x => x.MatchBetweenAllFields(yourText)));
    }
}
```